# Escape hash in post service in Java

Tags: spring-boot

I am writing a Test case in Spring boot 1.5.6 Release as shown below:

```
  @Test
  public void auditTrailSenderTest() throws Exception {
    String queryParameters = "auditActionId=#Create&objectTypeId=#AccBalance";
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v10/event?"+queryParameters))
           .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

The problem is that due to presence of hash in #Create and #AccBalance, the test case fails with status of 400. If i replace # with %23, then it is passed as '%23' without being converted to hash ('#') in Rest Api.

Is there any way to escape this number sign ('#') in query string parameters?

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode(queryParameters, "UTF8");` something like that.

Comment: The test case fails with status of 400